# Sorting only certain arrays in nested ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

I currently have a nested ngRepeat, where the inner loop iterates over a collection of items from its parent. An excerpt:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in persons">

 (Irrelevant code here.)

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th ng-click="setItemOrder('name')">Item name</th>
      <th ng-click="setItemOrder('number')">Item number</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in person.items | orderBy:itemOrder">
      <td>{{item.name}}
      <td>{{item.number}}
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

By clicking the table headers, I set the `itemOrder`-property in my controller to the name of the property I want `orderBy` to use:

```
$scope.setItemOrder = function(order){
  $scope.itemOrder = order;
}
```

This all works fine, except that if I click the headers in *one* `person`-div, the `item`-tables in *all* `person`-divs get sorted on that property.

Is there a way to make ngRepeat only apply `orderBy` to entries that match a certain criteria - for instance a certain index? Or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the property to respective person instance as follows:

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('testController', function($scope) {

  $scope.persons = [{
    items: [{
      name: 'test',
      number: 2
    }, {
      name: 'test1',
      number: 1
    }]
  }, {
    items: [{
      name: 'test3',
      number: 5
    }, {
      name: 'test4',
      number: 4
    }]
  }];

  $scope.setItemOrder = function(person, order) {
    person.itemOrder = order;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">
  <div ng-repeat="person in persons">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th ng-click="setItemOrder(person,'name')">Item name</th>
        <th ng-click="setItemOrder(person,'number')">Item number</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in person.items | orderBy:person.itemOrder">
        <td>{{item.name}}
          <td>{{item.number}}
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!

Comment: plus1 for the example

Answer (score 1):

You could add a ordering variable for each person and extend setItemOrder with the person object. Then you can call:

```
setItemOrder(person, 'name');
```

and then use it in the ngRepeat:

```
orderBy:person.itemOrder
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('testController', function($scope) {
 $scope.ordersort=true;
  $scope.orderfield='number';
  $scope.persons = {
    "items": [{
      "name": 'test',
      "number": 2
    }, {
      "name": 'test1',
      "number": 1
    }],
  
    "item1": [{
      "name": 'test3',
      "number": 5
    }, {
      "name": 'test4',
      "number": 4
    }]
  };

  $scope.setItemOrder = function(person, order) {
     $scope.orderfield=order;
    person.itemOrder = order;
    $scope.ordersort= !$scope.ordersort;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">
 
  <div ng-repeat="person in persons">
    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th ng-click="setItemOrder(person,'name')">Item name</th>
        <th ng-click="setItemOrder(person,'number')">Item number</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in person | orderBy:orderfield:ordersort">
        <td>{{item.name}}
          <td>{{item.number}}
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
```

I have modified your example. In this example table sorting is working perfectly. But It is not sorted the particular table when I click on that table header. Anyway to sort columns by specific table?

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('testController', function($scope) {

  $scope.persons = [{
    items: [{
      name: 'test',
      number: 2
    }, {
      name: 'test1',
      number: 1
    }]
  }, {
    items: [{
      name: 'test3',
      number: 5
    }, {
      name: 'test4',
      number: 4
    }]
  }];

  $scope.setItemOrder = function(person, order) {
    person.itemOrder = order;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">
  <div ng-repeat="person in persons">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th ng-click="setItemOrder(person,'name')">Item name</th>
        <th ng-click="setItemOrder(person,'number')">Item number</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in person.items | orderBy:person.itemOrder">
        <td>{{item.name}}
          <td>{{item.number}}
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
```